# Shooter game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, beginner, game

I have written a small game in javascript and I was wondering if the code is acceptable. I am reasonably new to javascript although I can't really get past the basics. All this code was originally in multiple files.

```js
function Enemy(x,y,w,h,moveX){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.speedX = 1;
 this.speedY = 1;
 this.dead = false;

 this.show = function(){
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
 }

 this.update = function(){
  if(this.dead == true){
   ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);  
  }
  else{
   this.show();
  }  

  this.move();

 }

 this.move = function(){
  this.x += this.speedX;
  if(this.x > canvas.width - this.w){
   this.speedX = -this.speedX;
  }
  else if (this.x < 0){
   this.speedX = -this.speedX;
  }
  
  this.y += this.speedY;
  if(this.y > canvas.height - this.h){
   this.speedY = -this.speedY;
  }
  else if (this.y < 0){
   this.speedY = -this.speedY;
  }
  
 }

}

function Bullet(x,y,w,h,up,down,left,right, sprite){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.hit = false;
 this.show = function(){
  if(sprite == null){
   ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
  }
  else{
   let img = new Image();
   img.src = sprite;
   ctx.drawImage(img,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h)
  }
 }

 this.moveX = function(dir){
  this.x += dir;
 }

 this.moveY = function(dir){
  this.y += dir;
 }

 this.update = function(){
  this.show();
  if(up) this.moveY(-5);
  if(down) this.moveY(5);
  if(left) this.moveX(-5);
  if(right) this.moveX(5);
 }

 this.clear = function(){
  ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
 }
}

function Player(x, y, w, h, sprite){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.show = function(){
  if(sprite == null){
   ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
  }
  else {
   let img = new Image();
   img.src = sprite;
   ctx.drawImage(img,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
  }
 }

 this.moveX = function(moveX){
  this.x += moveX;
 }

 this.moveY = function(moveY){
  this.y += moveY;
 }
 this.wallCollide = function(){
  if(this.x <= 0) this.x = 0;
  else if(this.x >= canvas.width - this.w) this.x = canvas.width - this.w;

  if(this.y <= 0) this.y = 0;
  else if(this.y >= canvas.height - this.h) this.y = canvas.height - this.h;
 }
 this.update = function(){
  this.show();
  this.wallCollide();
  if(keys.up) player.moveY(-2);
  if(keys.down) player.moveY(2);
  if(keys.right) player.moveX(2);
  if(keys.left) player.moveX(-2); 
 }


}


let canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanv');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let keys = {
 up: false,
 down: false,
 left: false,
 right: false
};
let player = new Player(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 40, 40);
let bullets = [];
let enemy = [];
let enemyCount = 3;
let totalEnemy = enemyCount;
let scoreNum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++){
 enemy.push(new Enemy(Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width),Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height),20,20, Math.floor(Math.random()*2)));
}
function Update(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 drawScore();
 player.update();

 //Draw Enemies
 for(let j = 0; j < enemy.length; j++){
  enemy[j].update();
  if(Collides(enemy[j], player)){
   location.reload();
  }
 }
 
 if(enemyCount == 0){
  enemyCount = totalEnemy;
  totalEnemy += 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++){
   enemy.push(new Enemy(Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width),Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height),20,20, Math.floor(Math.random()*2)));
  }
  for(let j = 0; j < enemy.length; j++){
   enemy[j].speedX += 1;
   enemy[j].speedY += 1;
  }
 }


 //Draw bullets
 for(let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
  bullets[i].update();
  if(bullets[i].x > canvas.width - bullets[i].w || bullets[i].x < 0){
   bullets.splice(i,1);
  }
  for(let j = 0; j < enemy.length; j++){
   if (Collides(bullets[i], enemy[j])){
    bullets.splice(i,1);
    enemy.splice(j,1);
    enemyCount -= 1;
    scoreNum +=  1;
   }
  }
 }

}


window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
 switch(event.keyCode){
  case 87:
   keys.up = true;
   break;
  case 83:
   keys.down = true;
   break;
  case 68:
   keys.right = true;
   break;
  case 65:
   keys.left = true;
   break;
  case 38:
   bullets.push(new Bullet(player.x+15, player.y+15, 5, 5,true,false,false,false));
   break;
  case 40:
   bullets.push(new Bullet(player.x+15, player.y+15, 5, 5,false,true,false,false))
   break;
  case 37:
   bullets.push(new Bullet(player.x+15, player.y+15, 5, 5,false,false,true,false))
   break;
  case 39:
   bullets.push(new Bullet(player.x+15, player.y+15, 5, 5,false,false,false,true))

 }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
 switch(event.keyCode){
  case 87:
   keys.up = false;
   break;
  case 83:
   keys.down = false;
   break;
  case 68:
   keys.right = false;
   break;
  case 65:
   keys.left = false;
   break;
 
 }
});

function Collides(spriteOne, spriteTwo){
 if(spriteOne.x > spriteTwo.x && spriteOne.x < spriteTwo.x+spriteTwo.w && spriteOne.y > spriteTwo.y && spriteOne.y < spriteTwo.y + spriteTwo.h){
  return true;
 }
}



function drawScore(){
 let scoreText = document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = scoreNum + " Enemies Killed";
}
setInterval(Update, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanv" width="800" height="600" style="background-color: lightgrey"></canvas>
<p id="score" style="position:absolute; top:0px"></p>
```

Comment: I get `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED` when running this -- does it work for everyone else?

Comment: Yes but it does not actually affect the code. It is an error thrown because I have not managed deleting objects very efficiently.

Comment: OK, it makes it difficult for me to play the game because the error screen is fairly large and apparently can't be closed.

Comment: I think that is just a problem with the way they are run on this site. If you want you can try to copy and paste all the code into a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if the code is acceptable

The code is somewhat acceptable, though please consider the suggestions below- especially the first one!

#### Instance/Prototype Methods

It would be much more efficient to define the methods on the prototypes instead of attaching to each instance.

For example, take the methods out of the *Enemy* constructor:

```
this.show = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}

this.update = function(){
    ....
```

And make those methods of the prototype (after the definition of the constructor function):

```
Enemy.prototype.show = function(){
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}

Enemy.prototype.update = function(){
         ...
```

That way each method is declared only once instead of once per each instance. That would have huge impacts on the memory used by the browser. For more information about that topic, read about it in [this post](https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/)

#### Conditional logic

The logic in the Enemy method `move()` that conditionally negates the speed, I.e.:

```
if(this.x > canvas.width - this.w){
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
}
else if (this.x < 0){
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
}
```

Could be simplified using [Logical *OR*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
if(this.x <0 || this.x > canvas.width - this.w){
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
}
```

#### Comparison operators

The first Enemy method has an *if* statement like below:

```
if(this.dead == true){
```

If the aim is to ensure that `this.dead` is both `true` and in fact a Boolean, then the [strict equality comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) (I.e. `===`) can be used.

```
if(this.dead === true){
```

Otherwise if any value that is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) will suffice then remove the `== true`.

```
if(this.dead){
```

Comment: Thanks. I recently learnt about the prototype class in javascript so in the future I will use that. Next time I will also use the other suggestions you made.